# Retrieving BitCoin Payments, Confirmation Question

Tags: api, blockchain.info

I'm receiving BitCoin payments via the blockchain.info api.

I notice it sends a confirmations parameter, and it also continues to call the callback url until the response is `*ok*`.

Instead of manually checking every x minutes via a third-party site to see whether or not txid has x confirmations, would it be possible to just not output `*ok*` until there is x confirmations?

I'm not sure whether or not the blockchain stops sending the callback, and was wondering if this is possible or not.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Yes, it will eventually stop sending callbacks.

> Expected Response
>
> In order to acknowledge successful processing of the callback the server should respond with the text `*ok*`. If the server responds with anything else the callback will be resent again every new block (approximately every 10 minutes) up to 1000 times (1 week).

https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

Comment: Thanks for that. I implemented it a few days ago and seems to be working fine.